# ASP.NET with Linux Docker autogenerated "Service 'failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, docker

Many people asking about problem with 
`Service 'web' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder`

This problem exist, when you trying to build Docker image from autogenerated Dockerfile for Linux in Visual Studio. I resolved that. Because many questions are not connected with ASP.NET directly i will help you, and tell what to do in this case in answer.

I tried to change:
`COPY ["Divorcer/Divorcer.csproj", "Divorcer/"]` to:

`COPY ["/Divorcer/Divorcer.csproj", "Divorcer/"]`,

`COPY ["./Divorcer/Divorcer.csproj", "Divorcer/"]`,

even to

`COPY ["~/.Divorcer/Divorcer.csproj", "Divorcer/"]`
Problem still exist.

So, as i told you Randomly generated path is like above.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is in Solution. When you creating new project named "Divorcer" VStudio making

```
Solution
  -- Project
```

Directories. This problem was resolved with simply bash commands (if you using screen OS you can do it with your mouse).

```
cd /Path/To/Solution/Project
mv Dockerfile ../
```

Its simply coping Dockerfile to **Solution directory** from **Project directory**. Now you can use docker build -t "someproject" . and it working. 
Make sure that you are in **Solution directory**! Have fun.